# Azure AD B2C Automatic logout - Authorization Code Flow with PKCE - Custom policies - msal

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

how can you have the application automatically logout as soon as the access token expires ? Here are the application details

1. Setup an Application in Azure AD B2C.
2. Using @zure/msal-browser and @azure/msal-react
3. setup the access token timeout in the Azure AD B2C custom policy

Observing that the application does not logout the user after access token expiry. A new access token is obtained using the refresh token.

Setting the refresh token timeout in the custom policies has no affect on the application.

Thanks,
-Sashi.

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check the web app session behaviour configuration in the custom policy for Azure AD B2C for automatically logging out the user after session timeout. The webapp session lifetime is the amount of time the Azure AD B2C session cookie is stored on the user's browser after successful authentication which can be set for maximum time of 24 hours. It has two parameters for setting this up, viz., rolling, and absolute where ‘rolling’ refers to extending the session every time user performs a cookie-based authentication and ‘absolute’ refers to the forced authentication that the user is subjected to after token timeout.

•   Also, if a valid id_token_hint is passed and the Require ID Token in logout requests is turned on, Azure AD B2C verifies that the value of post_logout_redirect_uri matches one of the application's configured redirects URIs before performing the redirect. This requirement of id_token in the logout requests allows your application to get the refresh token and reauthenticate the user post expiration of ‘ID_token’ timeout. However, if require ID token in logout requests parameter is set to ‘false’ as shown below, the application after logout redirects to the URI specified in the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter, regardless of the reply URLs that have been specified for the application.

```
  ‘ <UserJourneyBehaviors>
   <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" EnforceIdTokenHintOnLogout="false"/>
     <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
     <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
    <SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
     </UserJourneyBehaviors> ‘
```

Please find the below link for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#secure-your-logout-redirect

Comment: adding the addition EnforceIdTokenHintOnLogout="false" did not work for me.

Comment: Please check whether the 'offline_access' scope is included in the application when initiating a request for authorization code because this will ensure that the authorization server will revoke the refresh token after timeout since authentication policies are managed by it.

Comment: Yes, i do see the offline_access scope included in the token endpoint request. 
I am using @azure/msal-browser" and @azure/msal-react" in my SPA. I haven't found a way to not pass the offline_access scope in the token endpoint request.

For what i have been reading, msal 2.0 includes "openid", "profile" and "offline_access" are added by default. And i think the modules i am using in my SPA @azure/msal-browser" and @azure/msal-react" are built on top of msal 2.0

appreciate your comments

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this link and modify and check your custom policy settings accordingly - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Already did that. However, the user does not get logged out. MSAL keeps getting a fresh access token using the refresh token. I think the settings just expire the Azure AD b2c cookie.

Comment: This documentation suggests you to clear the cache to remove the access token from browser memory due to which refresh token might be accessed. Please refer and check - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-clear-token-cache